# IPTABLES: Why is my script not applied?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, iptables, linode

I am installing a fresh new VPS (from linode.com, if that matters) with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I wrote the following script for iptables:

```
#!/bin/sh

iptables -F

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -o eth0 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -i eth0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

This script should only allow 22, 80 and 443. It also allows outgoing DNS resolves.

I created and named this script `iptables.sh` as root and put it in `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d`. I did also `chmod +x`.

Now, after reboot, this script does not seem to be applied. I verified this by executing `iptables -S`, which gives:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

How do I progress from here? I am quite stuck right now.

**update**

I have no idea why, but after renaming `uptables.sh` to `iptables`, I cannot log in into my server anymore after a reboot. This makes me think that now the script is actually executed (and when it has `.sh` file extension not, why?) during boot and there is an error in my script. I am so confused.

Comment: "I cannot log in into my server anymore after a reboot". I think the line `iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443…` should use `--sports`, because in `OUTPUT` you want to allow response *from* port 22 etc. Notice UDP/53 has `dport`/`sport` rules corresponding to each other, not `dport`/`dport` nor `sport`/`sport`.

Comment: Oh, ofcourse! I will try again, THANKS A LOT for that tip.

Comment: This not working :(. I updated the script in my question, so its clears what my current version is.

Comment: Are you sure the interface is `eth0`? Modern Ubuntu may use something like `enpXsY`. [*Why is my network interface named enp0s25 instead of eth0?*](https://askubuntu.com/q/704361/693277)

Comment: It's indeed `eth0` in my case. I verified by running `ifconfig`, which gives `eth0` and `lo`.

Comment: I've found this about `state` module: "`ESTABLISHED` meaning that the packet is associated with a connection which has seen packets in both directions, `NEW` meaning that  the packet has started a new connection, or otherwise associated with a connection which has not seen packets in both directions". This suggests you should use `NEW,ESTABLISHED` instead of lone `ESTABLISHED`. I have no practical experience with this though, I may be very wrong.

Comment: I wll try that out!

Comment: The way I see it, your question is "why is (was) the script not applied?" My attempts *in comments* to solve the other issue (that manifested itself after the script was renamed and applied) were out of courtesy, because there's not a single question about it; it's a separate problem for sure. Now there's an "answer" that tries to fix your `iptables` commands without addressing the explicit question; in my opinion this is formally wrong. Before I downvote the answer, please state clearly whether the question is still "why was the script not applied?" or "how to make my firewall sane?"

Comment: You are absolutely right, my question was mainly about getting my script to do **something**. That has been solved. I should open a new issues for questions regarding the actual content/sanity of my rules. THANKS for your help!

Answer (score 0):

NEW is by itself and RELATED,ESTABLISHED go together.  When you connect via ssh the destination maybe port 22, but the source port is random that is why rule #2 in output does function as expected.

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Once these rules are in place your DNS request are part of the RELATED,ESTABLISHED traffic and you can delete your port 53 references.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. I don't think it's a good idea to do such things on all ports? Also, shouldn't it be something like `NEW, ESTABLISHED` for the `to` flow and `ESTABLISHED, RELATED` for the `from` flow?

Comment: I also don't understand your remark regarding 53. Isn't an outgoing DNS resolve a `NEW` request?

Comment: @DaveTeezo You can allow OUTBOUND port 53, but INPUT 53 is handled by RELATED,ESTABLISHED.  RELATED,ESTABLISHED on all ports is a lot easier than trying to do it per service.  Also the packet has to make it through the OUTPUT chain to become RELATED,ESTABLISHED, so if you block the connection in the OUTPUT chain it will never become RELATED or ESTABLISHED.